undefined reference to the class derived from an abstract class
I have an abstract class 'Question' and four derived classes from it: 'SAQuestion', 'TFQuestion', 'OCQuestion', 'MCQuestion'. I use polymorphism, so I can use class pointers and make them refer to my derived classes.
Here's how it looks in one of my files (the method creates a new 'Question' object and defines its type):
void Console::newQuestion() {
    // some code...    

    Question *quest; // Creating a class pointer
    string *answer = new string;

    switch(type) { // Defines a type of a question.
        case 1:
            // code again...
            quest = new SAQuestion(*context, *answer, *group); // Refers to SAQuestion
            break;
        case 2:
            // another code
            if(*answer == "T")
                quest = new TFQuestion(*context, true, *group); // Refers to TFQuestion
            else quest = new TFQuestion(*context, false, *group);

            break;
        case 3:
            quest = newOCQuestion(*context, *group); // Method that returns 'Question*'
            break; 
        case 4:
            quest = newMCQuestion(*context, *group); // Method that returns 'Question*'
            break;
    }

    DBManager::writeObjToFile<Question>("questions.txt", *quest); // Writes question to file
}

And also, here's how my method "writeObjToFile" looks:
    template<class T>
    static void writeObjToFile(string &&filename, const T &obj) {
        ofstream file(filename, ios::app);
        file << obj;
        file.close();
    }

But when I try to compile everything, gcc tells me this:
console.cpp:235:(.text+0x108e): undefined reference to `SAQuestion::SAQuestion(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
And the same error for every other class, derived from 'Question'.
Also it gives me error in dbmanager.h:
dbmanager.h:82:(.text$_ZN9DBManager14writeObjToFileI8QuestionEEvONSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_[_ZN9DBManager14writeObjToFileI8QuestionEEvONSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKT_]+0x47): undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, Question const&)'
Here's my question.h:
#ifndef COURSEWORK_QUESTION_H
#define COURSEWORK_QUESTION_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Question {
private:
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned short type = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> context; 
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> group;
public:
    Question(unsigned int newId, unsigned short newType, std::string &context, std::string &group);
    Question(std::string &context, std::string &group); 
    Question();

    unsigned int getId() { return id; }
    std::string getContext() { return *context; }
    std::string getGroup() { return *group; }
    unsigned int getType() { return type; }

    void changeGroup(std::string &group);

    void info();
    virtual bool checkAnswer(std::string &answer) = 0;
    virtual void changeAnswer(std::string &answer) = 0;
    
    Question(const Question &other);
    Question(Question &&other);

    Question &operator=(const Question &rhs);
    bool &operator==(const Question &rhs);
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Question &obj);

    virtual ~Question() {}
};

#endif

And its constructors and operator<< overload:
// Constructors
Question::Question(unsigned int newId, unsigned short newType, string &context, string &group): 
id{newId}, type{newType} {
    this->context = make_unique<string>(context);
    this->group = make_shared<string>(group);
}

Question::Question(string &context, string &group) {
    this->context = make_unique<string>(context);
    this->group = make_shared<string>(group);

    try {
        id = DBManager::availableQuestionId();
    }
    catch(string) {
        id = 0;
    }
}

Question::Question(): id{0}, type{0} {
    this->context = make_unique<string>();
    this->group = make_shared<string>();
}

Question::Question(const Question &other): id{other.id}, type{other.type},
context{make_unique<string>(*other.context)} {}

Question::Question(Question &&other): 
id{other.id}, type{other.type}, context{move(other.context)}, group{move(other.group)} {}

// Operator overload
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Question &obj) {
    os << obj.id << '\t' << obj.type << '\t' << *obj.context << '\t'
    << *obj.group << endl;
    return os;
}

And here's "saquestion.h" and its constructors with operator<< overload:
#ifndef COURSEWORK_SAQUESTION_H
#define COURSEWORK_SAQUESTION_H

#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include "question.h"

class SAQuestion : public Question {
private:
    unsigned int type = 1;
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> answer;
public:
    SAQuestion(unsigned int id, unsigned int type, std::string &context, std::string &answer, std::string &group);
    SAQuestion(std::string &context, std::string &answer, std::string &group);
    SAQuestion(std::string &context, std::string &group);
    
    std::string getAnswer() { return *answer; }

    void info();
    virtual bool checkAnswer(std::string &answer) override;
    virtual void changeAnswer(std::string &answer) override;

    SAQuestion(const SAQuestion &other);
    SAQuestion(SAQuestion &&other);

    SAQuestion &operator=(const SAQuestion &rhs);
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const SAQuestion &obj);
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, SAQuestion &obj);

    virtual ~SAQuestion() {}
};

#endif

SAQuestion::SAQuestion(unsigned int id, unsigned int type, std::string &context, std::string &answer, std::string &group):
Question{id, type, context, group} {
    this->answer = std::make_unique<std::string>(answer);
}

SAQuestion::SAQuestion(std::string &context, std::string &answer, std::string &group): Question{context, group} {
    this->answer = std::make_unique<std::string>(answer);
}

SAQuestion::SAQuestion(std::string &context, std::string group): Question{context, group} {
    this->answer = std::make_unique<std::string>();
}

SAQuestion::SAQuestion(const SAQuestion &other): Question{other}, answer{std::make_unique<std::string>(*other.answer)} {} 

SAQuestion::SAQuestion(SAQuestion &&other): Question{other}, answer{std::move(other.answer)} {
    this->answer = nullptr;
}

// Operator overload

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const SAQuestion &obj) {
    os << obj;
    os << *(obj.answer) << std::endl;
    return os;
}

(I know that's a lot of code, sorry for that)
What have I done wrong? I've tried changing arguments and return types, but nothing helps.

Are you implementing your templates in your headers? Remember you can't use a cpp file for templates implementations in most cases.

Where are your SAQuestion::SAQuestion definitions? Are they in the header file or a cpp file?

@AlanBirtles SAQuestion::SAQuestion and Question::Question are defined in the cpp files, 'saquestion.cpp' and 'question.cpp' respectively. I've just pasted the header file and parts from the cpp file in one code block, sorry for confusion.

@drescherjm Yes, my template methods are all in 'dbmanager.h'.

"gcc tells me this" Can you show the exact build command. For c++ code you should use  g++ and not gcc because gcc doesn't link to the standard library by default while g++ does.
